# Error sending erc20 tokens

Tags: web3js

I try to send erc20 tokens in this way

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

var Web3 = require('web3')

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/2a7d7b55629d44119f069a9239ea96fd'))

// set token source, destination and amount

var myAddress = ""

var toAddress = ""

var amount = web3.utils.toHex(1e16)

// get transaction count, later will used as nonce

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress).then(function(v){console.log(v); count = v})  


var privateKey = new Buffer('privatekey', 'hex')  
var abiArray = abiarray
var contractAddress = ''
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {from: myAddress})
var rawTransaction = {"from":myAddress, "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(2 * 1e9),"gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(210000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0","data":contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3.utils.toHex(count)} 
var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction)
transaction.sign(privateKey)
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call().then(function(balance){console.log(balance)})
```

but I get an error

```
var rawTransaction = {"from":myAddress, "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(2 * 1e9),"ga
sLimit":web3.utils.toHex(210000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0","data":contr
act.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3.utils.toHex(cou
nt)}


                                                                             ^

ReferenceError: count is not defined
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says 'count is not defined' ... you set the `nonce` to 'count' but did not define that. So you need to do something like this:

```
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount();
```

Comment: Thanks! Buy now i get another error:`    throw new Error('Provided address "'+ address +'" is invalid, the capitaliza
tion checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can\'t be conver
ted.');`

Comment: you're welcome. Just make sure the address is in checksum capitalization (mixed upper/lowercase) , that should fix it?